# How to set volume in ExoPlayer? SimpleExoPlayer had setVolume() api but SimpleExoPlayer is deprecated now

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using two `ExoPlayer` instances. I need to set custom volume to one of the `ExoPlayer` instances.

Previously, I was using `SimpleExoPlayer`s. Now I want to use `ExoPlayer` because `SimpleExoPlayer` is deprecated now. But `ExoPlayer` does not provide the `setVolume()` api nor any other similar api.

How can I set custom volume now with `ExoPlayer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But ExoPlayer does not provide the setVolume() api

Yes, [it does](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html#setVolume(float)). `ExoPlayer` implements `Player`, and `Player` has `setVolume()`.

Comment: Thanks. I could not find it earlier for some reason and android studio was also unhappy with this (⊙_⊙;) I did something wrong most probably.

Comment: Could you please also help with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418996/cannot-play-audio-with-exoplayer-during-an-ongoing-call)